# On hover show DIV flicker

Tags: css, hover, flicker

I am facing very annoying problem.
I have 2 div's like bellow, first div is product image, and second one is overlay that should be shown when user hovers over product image.
It does work, but when image is hovered, overlay doesnt stop flickering.
I tried few "hacks" by setting opacity and nothing works.

```
<div class="product-container">
        <div class="product-image"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">  
        <div class="overlay">PRICE</div>
</div>
```

URL is http://jsfiddle.net/MZ3eE/
I know JS could be used, but in this case i need pure CSS solution.

Comment: Is it a typo that .product-image div is unclosed, by looking at the format of the code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After looking at the new fiddle

you need to do this

```
.product-container:hover .overlay-box {
    display: block;
}
```

instead of

```
.product-img-box:hover + .overlay-box {
    display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/avxLA/1/

Comment: My bad, that was a typo :)
I did tried it like this, but it isnt working out, it is still flickering :( Could you take a look, maybe im missing something? http://goo.gl/lMO4OS

Comment: Your website is huge I cannot go through it out

Comment: You are right, i apologize, i made a new fiddle with code from there
http://jsfiddle.net/avxLA/
If this is too much time consuming, i apologize :)

Comment: I could swear i tried it this way :D Thanks a bunch for ur help!

Answer (score 6):

Apply the `:hover` to the .product-image div instead of the `img` like so:

```
.product-image:hover .overlay {
    display:block;
}
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MZ3eE/5/)

Answer (score 1):

For starters, there is an unclosed `<div>` there, so not quite sure how you want it. Anyway if you want it like this:

```
<div class="product-container">
        <div class="product-image">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
            <div class="overlay">PRICE</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

then like others said :

```
.product-image:hover .overlay {display:block;}
```

will do fine. Otherwise if you want it like that(which makes more sense tbh):

```
<div class="product-container">
    <div class="product-image"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"></div>
    <div class="overlay">PRICE</div>
</div>
```

you should put it on the containers `:hover` like that :

```
.product-container:hover .overlay {display:block;}
```