# change display none to block when when parent is flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

Problem with -

```
.popupcard_first:hover .popupcard_first { 
    display: block; 
}
```

I want to connect `:hover` to first card of good, but only to way I've found to get it work is change `.popupcard`... to

```
.featured_cards:hover .popupcard_first { 
    display: block; 
}
```

But this is not what i need, cause it works to every element of the row

```
<div class="featured_cards">

            <div class="card_one"><a href=""><img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Share/icon/Logos//jsfiddle1600.png" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="popupcard_first">
                <div class="circle"><a href=""><img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Share/icon/Logos//jsfiddle1600.png" alt=""></a></div>
                <div class="textname">Fishnet Chair</div>
                <div class="smalltextname">Seat and back with upholstery made of cold cure foam</div>
            </div>

            <div class="cards center two"><a href=""><img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Share/icon/Logos//jsfiddle1600.png" alt=""></a>
            </div>

            <div class="cards center three"><a href=""><img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Share/icon/Logos//jsfiddle1600.png" alt=""></a></div>

            <div class="cards edge four"><a href=""><img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Share/icon/Logos//jsfiddle1600.png" alt=""></a></div></div>
```

CSS

```
*{
  width 1380px;
}
img[title='arrow'] {
    display: inline;
    width: 9px;
    height: 13px;
}
.featured_cards img{
  width: 270px;
  height: 270px;
}
.featured_cards {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-right: 98px;
    margin-left: 98px;
    position: relative;
    height: 270px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.popupcard_first {
    height: 270px;
    width: 270px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0.9;
    display: none;
}

.featured_cards:hover .popupcard_first {
    display: block;
}

.circle {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    object-fit: contain;
    border-radius: 24px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4.9px 0.2px rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.35);
    margin: 62px 111px 0px 111px;
}

.circle img {
    margin: 14px 18px;
    width: 12px;
    height: 20px;
}

.textname {
    width: 145px;
    height: 17px;
    object-fit: contain;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.36;
    text-align: center;
    color: #212121;
    margin: 19px 62px 0 63px;
}

.smalltextname {
    width: 206px;
    height: 33px;
    object-fit: contain;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-size: 13.9px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.57;
    text-align: center;
    color: #6c6c6c;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 23px 32px 0px 32px;

}
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the code, its better if you place the div with class `popupcard_first` inside the div with class `card_one`. So the CSS changes are:

**CSS:**

```
.popupcard_first {
  height: 270px;
  width: 270px;
  position: absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.9;
  display: none;
}
.card_one{
  position:relative;
}
.card_one:hover .popupcard_first {
  display: block;
}
```

Why I recommend this method is because, I tried with your original code and it caused a flicker problem on element hover. Refer: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24678877/on-hover-show-div-flicker)

So how it goes is, first you need to set all the divs which are cards as `position: relative`, then set the popover div which is `popupcard_first` to `position; absolute` which will set the div position, relative to the parent who is `card_one`, then we tell that only when `card_one` div is hovered, the `popupcard_first` is shown.

Finally here is a working demo.

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

Let me know if you face any issues.